# Unit testing routing/controller in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Goal: test that a given url returns a given controller function.

In the process, I've broken into the routing system and I can't figure out how to test routes (or, for that matter, find the controller corresponding to the route :-/).

Sample code, which doesn't work:

```
[Test]       
public void kick_the_tires()
{
   var rc = new RouteCollection();

   Infrastructure.RouteRegistry.RegisterRoutes(rc);

   // get the route corresponding to name.
   var got = rc["name"];

   var expected = //What? foo is an internal type that can't be instantiated.

   Assert.AreEqual(foo, frob);
}
```

---

edit: Using the linked blog post from Simon for the stub class.

```
[TestCase("/", "~/", "Home", "Index")]
[TestCase("/", "api/command", "Other", "command")]
internal void stub_mocker(string apppath, string route, string expected_controller,\
  string expected_action)
{
  var rc = new RouteCollection();
  Infrastructure.RouteRegistry.RegisterRoutes(rc);

  var httpmock = new StubHttpContextForRouting(
      appPath: apppath,
      requestUrl: route);

  // this always returns null for everything but the Index case.
  var routeData = rc.GetRouteData(httpmock);

  var controller = routeData.Values["controller"];
  var action = routeData.Values["action"];
  Assert.AreEqual(expected_controller, controller);
  Assert.AreEqual(expected_action, action);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

All you are testing right now is if the routes are added to the collection, by accessing it by the route name, and not if the expected route will return given a virtual path. You need to obtain the route data as returned by the RouteCollection with a HttpContext.

Best way would be to use a mock or a stub for the HttpContext (or HttpContextBase) and call the RouteCollection's GetRouteData(HttpContextBase) method and inspect the route data.

There is a good example of this in Brad Wilson's blog: 
http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/testing-routing-and-url-generation-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Edit:You cannot get a controller instance from the RouteData itself. However, RouteData should give you enough information to know which controller will be instantiated. For example, if you have a controller at `MyProject.Controllers.HomeController` with an action `Home`, this should hold true in your test (using xUnit and Moq):

```
// Prepare
var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();

context.SetupGet(c => c.Request).Returns(request.Object);
context.SetupGet(c => c.Response).Returns(response.Object);
context.SetupGet(c => c.Session).Returns(session.Object);
context.SetupGet(c => c.Server).Returns(server.Object);
request.SetupGet(r => r.HttpMethod).Returns("GET");
request.SetupGet(r => r.PathInfo).Returns(String.Empty);
request.SetupGet(r => r.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath).Returns("~/Home");


var expectedHandler = typeof (HomeController).GetMethod("Index", Type.EmptyTypes);

var data = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(context.Object);

Assert.NotNull(data);

var handler = (MethodInfo) data.DataTokens["actionMethod"];
Assert.Equal(expectedHandler, handler);
```

Comment: Thanks, Simon (Welcome to StackOverflow!). Can you comment on how to get a controller back from a route, as that's what I'm really trying to do?

Comment: Simon, this isn't working. I don't totally grasp the MVC4 world, but I believe DataToken is supposed to contain the params from the route, not the methods being triggered.

Comment: Followup: RouteData.Route.DataTokens doesn't exist; Routedata.DataTokens does.

Comment: I edited my example to provide an example of mocking the HttpContext, and fixed the redundancy for the DataTokens dictionary. The code passes my unit test (with a different controller).

DataTokens will contain any extra properties that are passed to route handlers. The constraints, namespaces, etc.. are contained in the Values dictionary. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routedata.datatokens.aspx

Comment: Simon, GetRouteData keeps returning null for non-index lookups. I've hacked around it for a while and have been looking at purported source. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by non-index lookups. Could you update your question with the code that you are up to and is not working?

Comment: Note. I'm pretty sure what's going on is that GetRouteData is not correctly matching the urls I'm passing in. This could be because the route registry itself is using MapHttpRoute and the index route registration routine uses MapRoute. Examining the different routes in `rc` using the debugger, there are definitely different types living in it.

Comment: My test were done on ApiController, it shouldn't affect the outcome. I noticed that your Index route is `~/` but your `api/command` forgo the virtual path. Have you tried with `~/api/command` ? As far as I remember, this will work for Virtual Path only. Also, make sure the Stubbed HttpContext.Request Method is the correct one (GET, POST, PUT) and all the parameters, if any. HttpContext mocking has always been a pain.

Comment: Simon: ~/api/command gives a not implemented error (which is odd, because it SHOULD exist). It should be all GET at this point.

Comment: If your Stub does not implement some method / parameter, could it throw NotImplemented? I've unit tested mostly with mocks and I'm probably not as familiar as you are with stubs. If your stub is implementing HttpContextBase, alot of the property throws NotImplemented by default and you really have to poke around to find what GetRouteData needs from the HttpContext as it's quite opaque.

Comment: Simon: I finally got it working. I had to force the return type of the httpmethod to be GET.  I also had to use alphabetical values in the string constraints (apparently 100 isn't a string). Thank you SO MUCH for your help. :-)

Comment: Ahah, something obscure as usual. Glad I could be of help. :)

Comment: @PaulNathan - is this an accepted answer? Or, does it need to be tweaked for us copy/paster folk who follow up on this?

Comment: @bkwdesign: Two+ years later, I can't answer that, I haven't used MVC4 since this project.

Answer (score 1):

I've had prety good experience with [MVCContrib's Testhelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper)

Take a look at this [test of testhelper.](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/network/Show#src/MVCContrib.UnitTests/TestHelper/RoutesTest.cs)

Saves a lot of hassles around stubbing `HttpContext` etc.

Also if you are on MVC4, have a look at [this Nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/StudioDonder.MvcContrib.Mvc4.TestHelper/) which is a fork for MVC4.

Comment: I agree with you, testing anything that requires HttpContext is painful enough that a library that does the work for you is always useful.